# Weird placeholder when I press the key to put accent in letter

Tags: language-support

I see this super weird placeholder when I press RIGHT ALT, the key that I use to put accent on letters. I would like to know if this is a bug, and if it can be fixed. That's what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have defined <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to serve as your [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose), and if so, that symbol is there to let you know that it's waiting for a compose sequence.

It's not a bug; it's expected built-in behavior.